# Gradle MinSDK 15 to 10 Build Error

Tags: java, android

I recently discovered an old phone of mine is not supported by an app that I'm looking to build. So I've decided to change the minSDK of my app.

**From**

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.x7n7.sampleaudio"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

**To**

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.x7n7.sampleaudio"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Which gives me the following error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 10 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1] /.../AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v4" to force usage

I looked up the error, and found similiar (but not exactly the same versions). So I copied a similiar problem's solution into my android manifest by adding

`<use-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="anrdoid.support.v4"></use-sdk>` and `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to my android manifest file. It now looks like this:

**New Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.x7n7.sampleaudio">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>

    <use-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="anrdoid.support.v4"></use-sdk>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Problem**

I still get the same build error before and after doing what the error tells me to do, and what it looks like is the correct solution after searching.

**Full build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.x7n7.sampleaudio"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.github.wendykierp:JTransforms:3.0'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AppCompat library v26 does not work with anything below Sdk 14. They did the same thing as Google Play Services dropping support for older versions

Answer (score 0):

The minimum API level to use Support lib version 26 or higher is 14. 
You can't go below that if you want to use Support lib version 26+

Check this:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html
Under "Revision 26.0.0 Alpha 1"

To "fix" it, you'll have to use version 25.4 of the support lib, which is the newest version that supports API 10.